# I can't see applications other than those in launcher

Tags: launcher

I have Ubuntu 11.10. When I installed it I could see my applications, but anytime after installation, I can't see my applications and I can only use  the aplications that I have in my laucher.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Do you mean that after installing 11.10 you can't boot into it?

Answer (score 1):

Hare's how to browse all the installed applications in Unity!

Press Super Key (Windows key) or click on the top most button in launcher to open the Dash.

[image]

Now,

1. Click on the application lens in lower most part of the dash then,
2. Click on the installed (See more results).

[image]

Just scroll down and you'll see all the applications installed on your system.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Dash Home (Ubuntu logo on the top left corner) and type the application name.The Dash will show your application, just click on it, see it launches.You can drag and drop the specific application icons to the launcher for easy access as well.